# How do I open this ceiling light fixture?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

I am trying to replace the bulb in this ceiling light but I cannot figure out how to open it.

The glass dome is supported by the bottom ring and can be rotated freely.

Presumably I need to disconnect the bottom ring from the top one, however as you can see there is no visible screw or finial sticking out.

I also tried twisting the whole thing with no success.

Any advice on what to try next?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two rings.

Try twisting the bottom ring only counterclockwise and it should become loose.

Be careful that the ring is also holding the glass dome.

Now you can unscrew the upper ring if you have to

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't unscrew, try pulling down gently. Some of these domes are held in place by spring wires, and can be slid down a few inches and then unhooked.

Answer (score 0):

If that's a modern LED light, then the "bulb" may not be user-serviceable.  You throw out the entire unit when the LED fails.  If you're able to pull down the unit using @keshlam or @Ruskes methods, and you only have two wires disappearing into the unit without any removable door/hatch/plug, then the whole thing should be replaced.